# How to add values with backquotes

Tags: validation, grammar, xtext

I have create the grammar

```
grammar com.iamsoft.net.Validate with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate validate "http://www.iamsoft.com/net/Validate"

Model:
    netDescription+=DescriptionPair+;

DescriptionPair:TSO;
TSO:
    name=TSO_NAME '='  '"' value=BOOLEAN '"';

terminal BOOLEAN:
    'on' | 'off';


terminal TSO_NAME:
    'TSO_' ID;
```

And during validation of the string

```
TSO_eth1="off"
```

Have following error message

> mismatched input '"off"' expecting '"'

But if I remove double quotes from rule TSO, grammar correctly validate string

> TSO_eth1=off

So how to add double quotes to the grammar?

Regards,
Vladimir

Comment: can feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inheritance of terminals grammar which already contains a string rule

depending on if you need the STRING terminal rule anywhere else you have following options

(1) dont inherit from terminals grammar and copy&paste the terminal rules and hidden clause from the terminals grammar to your grammar

(2) override the STRING rule with simething unused e.g. `terminal STRING: '@@@@@@willnenverbecalled@@@@@'`

(3) use a datatype rule + a valueconverter instead of your stuff `BOOLEAN: STRING` and `TSO: name=TSO_NAME '=' value=BOOLEAN;`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple STRING and add validation and content proposal. Your description pair is no longer bound to the BOOLEAN datatype but you can add further types in the future.

The STRING terminal also accepts single quotes, if this is not desired, you would still have to override the rule